# How to fetch multiple ID using xpath or cssSelector if its sharing the same classname

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

Was trying to fetch ID but was throwing *no element found* exception for the following code:

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='activity'][contains(.,'First Testing')]")).getAttribute("id");)

System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='activity'][contains(text(), 'Second Testing')]")).getAttribute("id"));
```

The above two code lines didn't worked threw *no elements found exception*

Please find the HTML :

```
<a id="id_106" class="activity"> 
<strong>teena</strong>: <label id="check_label">
<em class="Highlight" style="padding: 1px; box-shadow: rgb(229, 229, 229) 1px 1px; border-radius: 3px; background-color: rgb(0, 191, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: inherit;" match="Test" loopnumber="79991">Test</em> First Testing
</label>
</a>

<a id="id_109" class="activity"> 
<strong>maria</strong>: <label id="check_label">
<em class="Highlight" style="padding: 1px; box-shadow: rgb(229, 229, 229) 1px 1px; border-radius: 3px; background-color: rgb(0, 191, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-style: inherit;" match="amazon" loopnumber="791951">Test</em> Second Testing 
</label>
</a>
```

Here since contents inside strong tag is not constant and only element constant is text values in label tag (First Testing/Second Testing) and classname is same

Expected output :

```
id_106
id_109
```

Comment: why `//a[@class='activity'][contains(.,'First Testing')]`? _First Testing_ or _Second Testing_ is precisely not within the `<a>` tag but within it's descendant `<label>`

Comment: yeah correct noted, I missed that, thanks a lot @undetectedSelenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the texts *id_106* and *id_109* you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- To print ***id_106***:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@id='check_label' and contains(.,'First Testing')]//parent::a")).getAttribute("id"));
  ```
- To print ***id_109***:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@id='check_label' and contains(.,'Second Testing')]//parent::a")).getAttribute("id"));
  ```